# How to migrate Custom List w/ Attachments to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2007, custom-list, migration, attachments, 2003

Is there a way to migrate Custom List w/ Attachments to the SharePoint 2013?

Currently we are migrating from SharePoint 2003 to SharePoint 2013, now I am just doing copy paste to datasheet view to transfer the data to the new 2013 custom list. My problem is that I can't find any way to migrate also the attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! There's still way to migrate this custom list with attachments. :)

Here's what what i did in my 5000+ data w/ attachments custom list:

1. Migrate all first the data from Old to New Custom List by copying data from Old Custom List and pasting it to the New Custom List via Data Sheet View.
2. Create an excel spreadsheet and copy paste the ID column of the Old CustomList Data and the new ID of the new CustomList Migrated Data.

Ex:

```
OLD-ID   | NEW-ID
345      |  1
346      |  2
```

3. Open existing Document Library on the old site , then navigate to your CustomList where you will see attachments folder. Inside the attachments folder resides all attachments folder named using the ID column used in the CustomList.

Ex.

```
File Explorer:

Attachments > 345 > sample.pdf,test.jpg
            > 345 > abc.xlsx
.....
```

4. Copy Paste the attachments folder on your Local Machine and create an application that will rename the old folder to new folder name based on the excel spreadsheet.
5. Run your program then after that you can now navigate to the Attachments folder of the new site then copy paste all the items renamed on your local machine inside the new Custom List attachments folder.
6. After that, Navigate now on your New Custom List and its now populated with their respective attachments file.

You now have successfully migrated Custom List with attachments. :)

Hope this help other folks having same problem migrating custom list w/ attachments.

Regards!

Comment: And you did that for 5000+ items? You should take a look at any of the content migration tools out there, they do that sort of thing in minutes.

Comment: Your correct @Louis theres migration tool that can be used in doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. My first idea was to use list templates, where you can include content, but those files are not compatible between 2003 and 2013.
A 3rd party tool like Sharegate can export/import between SharePoint sites.

The only other way to get the attachments is by opening the list in explorer view. The attachments are in a hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with ms access too...it will even grab your files...

it will take a long time especially if you have a lot of items, just import it and then export it to the location you want and BOOM!! done....